# Admin URL and DB config for development area

Tags: admin, base-url, staging

I recently created a Development/Staging copy of my site/database and everything seems to be working correctly on the front end. So when I visit **dev.mysite.com** I am able to browse my store and it stays on **dev.mysite.com**.

But when I try to login/access the admin area at **dev.mysite.com/admin/** it keeps redirecting me to **www.mysite.com/admin/**

I updated my **core_config_data** table in the Dev DB for both secure and insecure url's to **dev.mysite.com/**. I know that the front end is using the dev DB because I update my **local.xml**.

I can actually access **dev.mysite.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/web/...** but i have to manually change the URL in the address bar. When I click around the admin area it always sends me back to **www**

I am also noticing that in the Dev Admin when i navigate to **System>Configuration>Web>Base URL** it is still showing **www.mysite.com/** which is leading me to believe that the Dev admin area is still using the Production DB and not the Dev DB.

Is there some sort of caching or setting(s) that I am not aware of?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Clear Magento cache, check in core_config_data for all store view and clear browser

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. Since Im using a multi-store setup, it seems it was an issue with my HTACCESS along with the Secure URL in core_config_data. I had to set my Secure Base URL to http since my certificate does not support the `dev.mysite.com` domain. Here are my new settings

**Development/Staging Site**

HTACCESS:

```
SetEnvIf Host dev\.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=mysite_com
SetEnvIf Host dev\.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

DATABASE core_config_data

```
web/unsecure/base_url = http://dev.mysite.com/
web/secure/base_url = http://dev.mysite.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that all of your base URLs in the core_config_data database table have been updated to your dev site's url.

This article explains how to do this: https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Update+Site+URL+in+core_config_data+after+you+move+to+a+new+server+or+change+domains

Comment: Ok, I cleared the /var/cache/ dev directory and updated `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to the new dev URL in `core_config_data` and still same issue. I did see a folder called /var/minicache/ would that need to be cleared as well?